# Do I need a 'wireless access point' or a router?

Tags: networking, router, wifi

If I have a wired network with a DHCP-enabled router, do I need a wireless access point or a router to give wifi access to the office? Do all wifi routers have a mode for reverting to access points if the routing isn't necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, yes. Most wireless routers will work as wireless access points just the same. You will probably want to disable the DHCP functionality, though, and use a regular LAN port for your upstream connection instead of the WAN port.

How many people are you talking about giving access to? Many consumer-grade wireless routers will start misbehaving after a dozen or two concurrent users.

Comment: `"Many consumer-grade wireless routers will start misbehaving after a dozen or two concurrent users"` A lot of enterprise grade access points will do the same :)

Comment: @Joel So true :-)

Answer (score 2):

What you seems to need is AP. Some wireless routers can act as wireless bridge.